# CSS for web page that fills screen and has long list within

Tags: html, css, overflow

I want to make a web page that fills the entire available browserwindow. That is not a problem. But on that page I want to display a long list. The element with that list should get a scrolbar to scroll through the list.
With the html I have now, the page is stretched by the pushing list.
This is my page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body style="height: 100%; margin:0; background-color: #FFFF00">
<header>
    <H1>Header of page with long list of items</H1>
</header>
<section style="position: absolute; top: 80px; bottom: 5px; width:100%; background-color: red">
    <div style="background-color: #BBBBBB">
        <div style="overflow-y: auto;">
            <ol>
                <li><h3>Item in the list</h3></li>
                <li><h3>Item in the list</h3></li>
                <li><h3>Item in the list</h3></li>
                <li><h3>Item in the list</h3></li>
                <li><h3>Item in the list</h3></li>
                <li><h3>Item in the list</h3></li>
                <li><h3>Item in the list</h3></li>
                <li><h3>Item in the list</h3></li>
                <li><h3>Item in the list</h3></li>
                <li><h3>Item in the list</h3></li>
                <li><h3>Item in the list</h3></li>
                <li><h3>Item in the list</h3></li>
                <li><h3>Item in the list</h3></li>
                <li><h3>Item in the list</h3></li>
                <li><h3>Item in the list</h3></li>
                <li><h3>Item in the list</h3></li>
                <li><h3>Item in the list</h3></li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Simply add a `height` - the content after it will be scrollable after that, also - why use inline-styles when you can use an external stylesheet?

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: The shown code is just to show the problem. No need to have the style in e separate file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/133/

**CSS**

```
body {
      height: 100vh;
      background-color: #FFFF00;
      overflow-y: hidden;
  }

  .list {
      height: 100vh;
  }

  .list ol {
      overflow-y: scroll;
      height: 100%;
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<header>
    <H1>Header of page with long list of items</H1>
</header>
<section style="position: absolute; top: 80px; bottom: 5px; width:100%; background-color: red">
    <div style="background-color: #BBBBBB">
        <div class="list">
            <ol>
                <li><h3>Item in the list</h3></li>
                <li><h3>Item in the list</h3></li>
                <li><h3>Item in the list</h3></li>
                <li><h3>Item in the list</h3></li>
                <li><h3>Item in the list</h3></li>
                <li><h3>Item in the list</h3></li>
                <li><h3>Item in the list</h3></li>
                <li><h3>Item in the list</h3></li>
                <li><h3>Item in the list</h3></li>
                <li><h3>Item in the list</h3></li>
                <li><h3>Item in the list</h3></li>
                <li><h3>Item in the list</h3></li>
                <li><h3>Item in the list</h3></li>
                <li><h3>Item in the list</h3></li>
                <li><h3>Item in the list</h3></li>
                <li><h3>Item in the list</h3></li>
                <li><h3>Item in the list</h3></li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you Nenad. I had to reduce the heigth of .list. ol to 90% to see the last item, but then it worked. I missed the height unit 'vh'.

Comment: You're welcome. Please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem.